# How to pass a specific list of files to `binaryFiles`

Tags: python, pyspark

A `Context` object has a `binaryFiles(path, minPartitions=None)`.  I know that I can put globs for the `path` argument, e.g. `'*.avro'`, but how can I pass in a specific list of files: `['a.avro', 'y.avro', 'z.avro']`?

Is there a general definition for what pySpark accepts for `path` type arguments?

Answer (score 0):

binaryFile method of sparkContext will provide RDD and takes path of type string not listOfString.

If you use below code you can pass list of paths and this will give you dataframe.

```
spark.read.format("binaryFile").load("pass list of file paths here")
```

Refer documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-binaryFile.html).